# HTTParty headers strange behavior

Tags: ruby, httparty

### Context :

I'm using HTTParty to do a POST request on an API that accept `application/json`

My body is something like that (as a hash)

```
{:contact_id =>"12345679", 
 :items=> [
      {:contact_id=>"123456789", :quantity=>"1", :price=>"0"},
      {:contact_id=>"112315475", :quantity=>"2", :price=>"2"}
]}
```

### Issue :

When I write the following code, this is working :

```
HTTParty.post('https://some-url', body: content.to_json, headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json" } )
```

But when change only the `=>` symbol in headers, to `:` symbol, this is not working (the API respond that some parameters are missing)

```
HTTParty.post('https://some-url', body: content.to_json, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } )
```

### Question :

Why changing `"Content-Type" => "application/json"` to `"Content-Type": "application/json"` lead to errors ?

I think this is something with Ruby hash that I don't understand.

### Edit :

I think my question is not a duplicate of [Why is this string key in a hash converted to a symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513996/why-is-this-string-key-in-a-hash-converted-to-a-symbol)

It's important for HTTParty consumers, to know that **HTTParty do not accept symbols** for headers **but only strings**.

For more information, see 
[Content-Type Does not send when I try to use a new Hash syntax on header](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/472) and
[Passing headers and query params in HTTparty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691483/passing-headers-and-query-params-in-httparty)

Thank you @anothermh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash keys in Ruby can be any object type. For example, they can be strings or they can be symbols. Using a colon (`:`) in your hash key tells Ruby that you are using a symbol. The only way to use a string (or other object type, like Integer) for your key is to use hash rockets (`=>`).

When you enter `{ "Content-Type": "application/json" }`, Ruby will convert the string `"Content-Type"` to the symbol `:"Content-Type"`. You can see this yourself in the console:

```
{ "Content-Type": "application/json" }
=> { :"Content-Type" => "application/json" }
```

When you use a hash rocket it does not get converted and remains a string:

```
{ "Content-Type" => "application/json" }
=> { "Content-Type" => "application/json" }
```

HTTParty [does not work with symbolized keys](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/472).

Comment: so HTTParty only accept string as headers, if I understand well

Comment: Correct. Read more [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/472) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24691483/3784008).